# Is it possible to collapse or hide rows in SlickGrid?

Tags: jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I need `expand/collapse` feature to `show/hide` rows in `SlickGrid`.

So to implement this feature, I have a expand/collapse icon on the Grid header row. And by pressing it, it should Show/Hide all data of the grid (Toggle Visibility).

The feature I want to implement is exactly same as grouping where parent row can be expanded/collapsed by clicking on `**+ or -**` icon. But without applying grouping.

Answer (score -1):

Should be pretty easy. Just find the viewport div and toggle its visibility on click. Everything else should collapse around it.

Comment: Right. But how can I put expand collapse Icon on Header ?

Comment: Whoops. Actually, I tried it and the rest does not collapse. The rows div expands to fill the fixed outer div.  will have more of a look soon.  Re the menu, try this: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/160